# Google Earth Engine: Single Image Exported into 5 file (tiles)

Tags: javascript, gis, google-earth-engine

I have a image which when exported a single image is converted into 5 image tiles

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#large-file-exports

How can we overcome this issue? How can we reduce the file size so that I can obtain the desired image in a single tile when exported to google drive ??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUWsw.png)

Export.image.toDrive({image:PNClip_PreMon2014,description:prename+'ExportToDrivePreMon2014',fileNamePrefix:prename,region:roi,scale:10,maxPixels:1E13,fileFormat:'GeoTIFF',skipEmptyTiles: true});

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scale:10` in the export code.

This will reduce the size and file will be less tan 1 GB and be able to downloaded as a single file.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
    image:PNClip_PreMon2014,
    description:prename+'ExportToDrivePreMon2014',
    fileNamePrefix:prename,
    region:roi,
    maxPixels:1E13,
    fileFormat:'GeoTIFF',
    skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```